# Which free bug tracking tool gives better performance out of four tools (Bug Note, Mantis, Bug Tracker .NET, Trac)?

Tags: testing, bug-tracking

I have selected four free tools for web based defect tracking. They are:

- Bug Notes
- Mantis
- Bug Tracker .NET
- Trac from Project Locker Software

I am trying to decide between these four tools, given the following considerations:

1. If I Create 5 bugs in each tool, and click on 'report'. Can we generate graphs (bar graph, pie chart) or reports from any of them or all of them?
2. Which tool is taking less time for creating 5 bugs?
3. Which tool is taking less time does to launch the application in each tool?
4. If I upload a 500 MB document in each tool, which one takes less time or whether the tool is able to handle this size?
5. Whether the reports are generated by who raised the defect or the name of the defect assigned person?

Following all the considerations is mandatory.
Can anyone please suggest to me which one is good with the above considerations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mantis or Bug Tracker .NET..
both are very user friendly..
You can generate graph in both tool.
You can generate report by category,day,month,priority, by user,status etc..

Comment: Thank you Rohit and I gone through the Mantis in that there is no option for Graph reporting for bugs and in BugTracker .net there is no option for creating our own project, can you please suggest me above the same. Thanks.

Comment: in mantis there is option for report..go to summary, you will find it..also there is option in bt.net for graph..   you can download bt.net and customize it..then you can perform different option like add project, delete bug and so on..on demo you can't add your own project..

Comment: Thanks Rohit, I have down loaded the file from the following link, http://www.soft82.com/get/download/windows/bugtracker-net/ and then If I executed that program it is just for capturing the image, and If I want to install it is giving error related to IIS. Can you please tell me the process about to installation.

Comment: If you think my answer is proper then vote up yaar..Yaa got it..you should have IIS on your system..If you have IIS then go to C:/inetpub  put that bt.net folder here,,then you have create database for that..Once you create database you have to establish connection for database..go to web.config..put connection string over here ..If any doubt then feel free to ask..:)

Comment: Needs to Install IIS and then just run that one, Is this correct or not?

Comment: I have installed .Net 4.0 Frame work in my system. There is no ASP .net in this system., but it is web based defect tracking tool know?

Comment: Ok I will do that first and catch u later, Thank you so much Rohit.

Comment: R u online? Please join in the testing talk room

Comment: hi..am online..come in testing talk room..m there